# bracket expressions in grep patterns

Tags: regex, macos, bash, grep

I'm a bit confused about how grep interprets bracket expressions (OSX 1.8).

I have file with rows as follows:

```
1   foo 42.0
2   bar 42.1
20  foo 42.3
```

I want to write a regular expression that says: 'at the start of a line, match one or more digits then whitespace then the string foo'. So I try that:

```
cat foo | grep -e "^[0-9]+\sfoo"
```

But nothing is matched. Huh? What's going on here? I've dug around the documentation but I cannot seem to find any answer. The problem seems to be in my application of the 'one or more' character.

Note that I cannot use Perl-style expressions as this feature seems to be gone from grep in OSX 10.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a look at one of many [grep documentations](http://www.ss64.com/bash/grep.html) explaining use of modifiers.

`Grep` understands three types of regular expressions: `basic`, `extended` and `PCRE`.

With basic regexp in grep, quantifiers such as `?` and `+` have to be escaped with backslashes.

The repetition operators (or quantifiers) are as follows:

```
? The preceding item is optional and matched at most once.
* The preceding item will be matched zero or more times.
+ The preceding item will be matched one or more times.
```

..

```
grep -e '^[[:digit:]]\+[[:space:]]\+foo' foo
```

The `-E` modifier Interprets the *pattern* as an extended regular expression.

```
grep -E '^[0-9]+\s+foo' foo
```

Perl one-liner without using grep:

```
perl -ne '/^[\d ]+foo/ and print' foo
```

Comment: The above will work. Besides the failure to escape the `+`, the original pattern would only match a single whitespace character. It's not clear if the input uses tabs or multiple spaces. If it used multiple spaces, then that would be another reason the original pattern didn't match.

Comment: You don't need to escape `+` using extended modifier?

Comment: Hmm? I was not claiming there was anything wrong with your answer. I was clarifying that one of the problems you fixed was to accept multiple spaces. That said, I just tested and `\s` does not match spaces in the version of `grep` on my system, so you'd still need to use `[[:space:]]` as in your first example.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` sometimes handles brackets differently than Perl expressions do, but here the culprit seems to be that you haven't escaped the `+` quantifier. [Here's a useful page](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/regexp.html) summarizing differences. Try this:

```
cat foo | grep -e '^[0-9]\+\sfoo'
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for posting. This doesn't seem to work. Neither does the simplified expression "^[:digit:]+" which should match all lines. That's the crux of my issue.

Comment: Woops, you also need to escape the `+`. I switched my answer to single quotes to avoid backslash interpolation.

Comment: You need to escape + ? urgh :(

Comment: It's interesting to note, btw, that only the first example posted works. The second fails because \t is not recognised by grep. The third should work according to the doco but it does not.

Comment: Thats because the third should be `[[:space:]]`

Comment: Nice. Thank you hwnd!

Comment: @acheong: can you correct your post in line with the comments above? I'd like to accept it.

Comment: Edited to minimal correct portion. You should accept @hwnd's answer, though. Clearly I didn't really know what I was talking about, despite that I've been through the same frustrations for five years as a UNIX developer. (Kinda like how I can never remember what `tar` flags to use.)